# angularjs - Animating element after model updated

Tags: angularjs, css-animations

Picture a board with cards in different columns like trello.

In my model, each column is an array and the cards are just items inside the array.

When something causes a card to move between columns, I splice the origin array and pop the item onto the destination array. I want to illustrate this with a brief animation of the card moving across the screen.

Example:

Something happens in the model to move the card `C` to the second column. I want an animation of it moving from it before position to its after position.

```
before -
| A |    |   |
| B |    |   |
| C |    |   |
| D |    |   |

after -
| A |    | C |
| B |    |   |
| D |    |   |
|   |    |   |
```

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Comment: Yes, on my github (https://github.com/Kirschstein/board-simulation). Being an angular newbie though, I'm not exactly sure what would be the bits to copy into SO for the question!

Comment: the plunker template http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:nKLNBdve51sqOoKZAOUS?p=preview is a good start to illustrate something online, and you can just copy the relevant parts of controllers/directives/services/templates if you need to. You generally don't want to copy your whole project, just a part that can demonstrate your specific problem.

Comment: unpicking some parts of it is taking me some time! Plunker not seeming to support folders is tripping me up

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ng-animate` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate , http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/move) to apply classes during `ng-repeat` events, and you can use those classes to apply css transitions.